# How to call one function with different parameter types

Tags: java

Is it possible that below method can work for double, float and integer? In other words, when I send indexRange(10.0), below function will get and use 10.0 as double not int. In C++, there is concept template but I can do this wish with template but with Java, I don't know.

```
private int[] indexRange(int idx_max, int size) {

}
```

Comment: You need to study `Generic Methods`!

Comment: What's wrong with current implementation? When You send 10.0 it is double, not int. If want to send int send 10. If want to call particular method use explicit conversion (byte) 10. If want to use template, then make generic method or generic class. It is very similar to C++.

Comment: Generics are the Java equivalent of C++ templates, but they don't work on primitive types (int,double, etc...), only on references. It's unclear, though, what you are trying to do (what is this method supposed to accept and to return).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is concept of wildcard in java on generics. For this kind of problem you can use that.The generics provides compile-time safety.

```
private <? extends Number> indexRange(<? extends Number> idx_max, <? extends Number> size) 
{
}
```

It will takes only number(int,double,float) as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

you can overload function

```
private int t(int d, int s) {
    return 0;
}

private int t(double d, double s) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you probably need to provide a bit of an explanation, but this otherwise is likely viable.  Although I'm not sure if this is what the OP is looking for... question a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same in Java using Generic Methods.

You can write a single generic method declaration that can be called with arguments of different types. Based on the types of the arguments passed to the generic method, the compiler handles each method call appropriately. Following are the rules to define Generic Methods:

All generic method declarations have a type parameter section delimited by angle brackets (< and >) that precedes the method's return type ( < E > in the next example).

Each type parameter section contains one or more type parameters separated by commas. A type parameter, also known as a type variable, is an identifier that specifies a generic type name.

The type parameters can be used to declare the return type and act as placeholders for the types of the arguments passed to the generic method, which are known as actual type arguments.

A generic method's body is declared like that of any other method. Note that type parameters can represent only reference types, not primitive types (like int, double and char).

```
public class GenericMethodTest
{
// generic method printArray                         
public static < E > void printArray( E[] inputArray )
{
  // Display array elements              
     for ( E element : inputArray ){        
        System.out.printf( "%s ", element );
     }
     System.out.println();
}

public static void main( String args[] )
{
    // Create arrays of Integer, Double and Character
    Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Double[] doubleArray = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
    Character[] charArray = { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O' };

    System.out.println( "Array integerArray contains:" );
    printArray( intArray  ); // pass an Integer array

    System.out.println( "\nArray doubleArray contains:" );
    printArray( doubleArray ); // pass a Double array

    System.out.println( "\nArray characterArray contains:" );
    printArray( charArray ); // pass a Character array
} 
}

 //    Everything taken from TutorialsPoint.com!
```

Comment: but I donot want char can be paramater to the function. If I use your generic method, how can I gain restriction like that just Integer, double, float are permitted.

Comment: Just remove the lines for `Character` Class @Zmavus,and it's done!I gave only a simple example!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using [Generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) in Java

Read [Why Use Generics?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) that will give you the answer of this question.

Find more [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

sample code:

```
class MyRangeProgram<T> {
    private T[] indexRange(T idx_max, T size) {
        ...
    }
}

new MyRangeProgram<Integer>();
new MyRangeProgram<Double>();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
private int[] indexRange(Number idx_max, Number size) {
   // your code goes here.
}
```

Primitives double, float, int correspond to `Double`, `Float` and `Integer` wrapper classes respectively. And these classes extend from `Number` class. So your primitive parameters will first be auto-boxed, then they will be processed as Number instances.

Comment: @shekharsuman you are offensive! the op wants something common between parameters. your answer is accepting every parameter.

Comment: Sorry,not really so,But,I don't really find `something common` quoted anywhere.He only mentioned that it should predict the same behaviour. REALLY SORRY for commenting that way!